# Fetched object returns underfined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, fetch

I have my data objects that I need to fetch, looking like this:

```
const products = {
        one: {
            id: 1,
            name: 'One',
            image: oneImage,
            chair: {
                name: 'ChairName',
                image: myImage,
                colors: {
                    white: {
                        name: 'White',
                        image: myImage,
                    },
                    black: {
                        name: 'Black',
                        image: myImage,
                    },
                },
            },            
            },
        },
        two: {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Two',
            image: twoImage,
            chair: {
                name: 'Chair,
                image: myImage,
                colors: {
                    white: {
                        name: 'White',
                        image: myImage,
                    },
                    black: {
                        name: 'Black',
                        image: myImage,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };
```

I am fetching them with Object.value

```
const ProductsData = Object.values(products).map((data) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className="box" onClick={() => setSelectedData(data)}>
                 <img src={data.image} />
            </div>
           );
});
```

This code above works just fine, pointing out to selected data like this:

```
           {selectedData ? (
              <h1>{selectedData.name}</h1>
           ) : null}
```

But now I would like to map through the chair colors of selected Data, which causes errors.

What I tried to do was to just `{selectedData.chair.colors.name}`, which prints nothing and by `console.log` is `underfined`

How can I print selectedData of chair colors and how I can set the picked color as new selectedData? I am getting lost.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to choose color, then you need to store it in another state variable.

```
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = React.useState();
```

Use `Object.values` to iterate `chair.colors`

```
  {Object.values(selectedData.chair.colors).map(val => {
    return <div onClick={() => setSelectedColor(val.name)}>{val.name}</div>
  })
   }
```

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-mclaren-rcixq)

Comment: That actually works @Apostolos, but how can update now the image of selected color of the chair ? if I do `src={val.image}`it will post images of both colors, but I need to display only image of the selected color.

Comment: Sorry, I meant image of chair color. Currently there are printed names {val.name} of the colors, when I click on one of the color name it should set image of that color that has been selected.

Comment: check my updated sandbox. then you need to store an object instead of just a value as `selectedColor`. I added some sample images from internet

Comment: @Eliot just edited the link since it created a new codesandbox link

Comment: I see what you did and I am not that lost actually anymore, got the logic! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `selectedData.chair.colors.name`, look again in your structure. There is `selectedData.chair.colors.white.name` or `selectedData.chair.colors.black.name`

Comment: Thanks @Sowam, that's correct! But when Iam trying to do `selectedData.chair.colors.black.name`, it returns me error with cannot read property of name. Is there a way how to restrucutre my data so it will make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

`colors` is an object again. It does not have a property `name`. It has properties like `white` and `black` which are objects themselves.

Map through:

```
Object.values(selectedData.chair.colors)
```

```
let selectedChairColors = Object.values(selectedData.chair.colors)
;
console.log(selectedChairColors[0])
console.log(selectedChairColors[1])
```

You can log `selectedChairColors` to see that this will give you an array of values of colors property in chair of selectedData.

Looking at your sandbox it seems you are using no checks while running selectedData and hence the error. (Initially, selectedData is undefined).

This should work:

```
 <div>{selectedData && Object.values(selectedData.chair.colors).map((x)=>
        JSON.stringify(x)
      )}</div>
```

Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-black-gc370?file=/src/App.js) forked out of yours.

Comment: This case throws error property chair of underfined.

Comment: Saw your sandbox and added the null check. Please implement proper checks before using object properties.